# Compute the homology groups $H_k (X_g-D)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X_{g}$ be a genus g surface and let $D\subset X$ be an open disk inside it. Compute the homology groups $H_k (X_g-D)$.

I am considering the chain complex:

$0 \rightarrow C_2 \rightarrow C_1 \rightarrow C_0\rightarrow 0.$

$0 \rightarrow C_2^{'} \rightarrow C_1^{'} \rightarrow C_0^{'} \rightarrow 0.$

If the homolgy groups are:

$H_2(X_g)=1, \\ H_1(X_g)=2g, \\ H_0(X_g)=1$

I think I am trying to show:

$H_2(X_g-D)=0, \\ H_1(X_g-D)=2g, \\ H_0(X_g-D)=1$

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is correct. For this, write $X_g$ as a quotient of a polygon with the sides identified. For example $X_1 \cong T^2$ is the square with the usual gluing of the edges. You can assume that the disk $D$ that you are removing is at the center, and looking the picture should convince you that $X_g \backslash D$ retracts on a wedge of $2g$ circles (which corresponds to the fact that a polygon minus a disk retracts on its boundary) and you are done.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "retracts on a wedge of $2g$ circles"? If I drew the picture correctly, it looks like $X_1-D$ is a punctured torus.

Comment: @PrimeSpiralObserver : sorry I didn't answer to you before.You are right, now you can make the removed disk bigger and bigger inside the square; at the end of the day you will obtain a deformation retraction from the punctured torus to the boundary of the square (modulo the identification). The latter space is a wedge of circles, do this makes sense now ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. And this is enough to show $H_2(X_g−D)=0$?

Comment: @PrimeSpiralObserver : Yes, for any manifold $M$ of dimension $k$, we have $H^i(M) = 0$ if $i > k$.